# Problem with pulling docker images from gcr in kubernetes plugin / jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, docker-registry, pull

I have a gke cluster with a running jenkins master. I am trying to start a build. I am using a pipeline with a slave configured by the kubernetes plugin (pod Templates). I have a custom image for my jenkins slave published in gcr (private access). I have added credentials (google service account) for my gcr to jenkins. Nevertheless jenkins/kubernetes is failing to start-up a slave because the image can't be pulled from gcr. When I use public images (jnlp) there is no issue.
But when I try to use the image from gcr, kubernetes says:

```
Failed to pull image "eu.gcr.io/<project-id>/<image name>:<tag>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

Although the pod is running in the same project as the gcr.

I would expect jenkins to start the slave even if I use a image from gcr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the pod is running in a cluster in the same project, is not authenticated by default.

Is stated that you've already set up the Service Account and I assume that [there's a furnished key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys) in the Jenkins server.

If you're using the [Google OAuth Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+OAuth+Plugin) you can then also use the [Google Container Registry Auth Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Google+Container+Registry+Auth+Plugin) to [authenticate to a private GCR repository and pull the image](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-push-docker-image-to-google-container-registry-gcr-through-jenkins-job-52b9d5ce9f7f).

Comment: thanks with the Google Container Registry Auth Plugin it is working :)