# GKE Jenkins can't download image for slave

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm running Jenkins on GKE and having issue when running job - it can't download image for slave - anyone met similar issue - it happens whether I use private Container Registry on GCP or official `jenkins/jnlp-slave` image

```
jenkins-agent-dz3kg                                            0/1     ErrImagePull   0          66s     x.x.x.x     gke-x-default-pool-xxxxx-x   <none>           <none>
jenkins-agent-dz3kg                                            0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          73s    x.x.x.x     gke-x-default-pool-xxxxx-x   <none>           <none>
```

and the values file of jenkins helm is pretty plain

```
agent:
  image: "gcr.io/my-image"
  tag: "latest"
  podName: "jenkins-agent"
  TTYEnabled: true
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "1"
      memory: "1Gi"
    limits:
      cpu: "4"
      memory: "4Gi"
```

jenkins installed with helm 2.13.1 and config above

```
helm install stable/jenkins --name jenkins -f jenkins.yaml
```

and to show that image is there

```
$ gcloud container images list
NAME
gcr.io/my-project/my-image
```

does the jenkins need some special permissons or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the slave is not authenticated within GCP

[Private registries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry) may require keys to read images from them. Credentials can be provided in several ways:

- Per-cluster
- automatically configured on Google Compute Engine or Google Kubernetes Engine
- all pods can read the project’s private registry

Those 2 toutorials should be helpful

- https://itnext.io/setup-jenkins-with-google-container-registry-2f8d39aaa275
- https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-container-registry-auth

Specially step 1 and step 2 from the first tutorial.

> 1.Create a service account which has full access to GCR in Google Cloud.
>
> 2.In jenkins, create a credential for this service account with Google OAuth Credentials plugin.
>
> 3.Create a pull/push build step with docker-build-step plugin, and set the registry url to GCR.
>
> 4.Google Container Registry Auth plugin will provide the credential created in Step 2 to docker when the build step is executed.

Comment: this kinda works but not really, it's for after you have deployed slave - to contact GCP and download some images from there - I have Jenkins on Kubernetes - and the slave itself uses Container Registry as it's base image - and he can't even do that - any thoughts on that ?

Comment: Hi @CptDolphin, any errors? Same like, for example, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374517/problem-with-pulling-docker-images-from-gcr-in-kubernetes-plugin-jenkins)?

Comment: resolved but damn was the solution simple.. in manage jenkins -> configure on the bottom in cloud -> kubernetes -> pod -> details  -> Docker Image I had to add the project path gcr.io/<my-project>/<my-image>:latest